# Running Portainer on Windows 10 Version 1709 with Linux Container feature

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using Docker for Windows 17.09 CE I can run the following code on a PowerShell console:

`` docker service create ` 
--name portainer `
--publish 9000:9000 `
--constraint 'node.role == manager' `
--mount type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock `
portainer/portainer `
-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ``

Now I am running Windows 10 Version 1709 I started experimenting with Docker for Windows 17.11 CE with the native Linux containers feature enabled. When running this code I get the following error:

`invalid mount target, must be an absolute path: /var/run/docker.sock`

How can I fix this?

-- edit:

I also tried without the `--mount` directive:

`` docker service create ` 
--name portainer `
--publish 9000:9000 `
--constraint 'node.role == manager' `
portainer/portainer `
-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock ``

This resulted in the following error:

`overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks
1/1: HNS failed with error : The parameter is incorrect.`

Comment: remove the mount command and see if it works?

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for the suggestion! I tried it out and changed my original question with the result. Can you explain why this binding is not necessary anymore with native Linux containers? But still, the HNS (Hyper-v Network System?) runs into an error. How can I fix this? I also quickly read through https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/606 that summarizes some vague workarounds.